# Upload the Flink task jar package to the Flink cluster through Java code

Tags: java, apache-flink

Do not use streamexecutionenvironment.Createremoteenvironment(), but now I have a jar package. I want to upload it directly to the Flink cluster, just like the submit new job of flinkweb, but it uses code.How do I implement this feature?

Answer (score 2):

You can give it a try using the Flink REST API: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/rest_api/#jars-upload

Comment: Thank you very much. What you said is very useful